# Adding a text on image coming from server dynamically

Tags: android

I am downloading some images from server at run time through web service, how i can put the text over it.

I have used this code but this gives exception.

url = new URL(imgUrl);

```
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                    .openConnection();
            urlConnection.connect();

            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            File cacheDirectory = getBaseContext().getCacheDir();

            // Temporary file to store the downloaded image
            File tmpFile = new File(cacheDirectory.getPath() + "/wpta_"
                    + position + ".png");

            // The FileOutputStream to the temporary file
            FileOutputStream fOutStream = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile);

            // Creating a bitmap from the downloaded inputstream
            Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(iStream);

            // Writing the bitmap to the temporary file as png file
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, fOutStream);

            Canvas g = new Canvas(b);
            Paint p = new Paint();
            p.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            p.setAntiAlias(true);
            g.drawText("Text", 10, 10, p);

            // Flush the FileOutputStream
            fOutStream.flush();

            // Close the FileOutputStream
            fOutStream.close();

            // Create a hashmap object to store image path and its position
            // in the listview
            HashMap<String, Object> hmBitmap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

            // Storing the path to the temporary image file
            hmBitmap.put("flag", tmpFile.getPath());

            // Storing the position of the image in the listview
            hmBitmap.put("position", position);
```

Comment: show us what you have tried :)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to mind is to use the `draw(Canvas)` method in a `TextView` object.

You can create a `Canvas object` from the `bitmap` by using:

```
new Canvas(bitmap)
```

then draw a `TextView` into the same Canvas.